# Best way to declare array size in C++

Tags: c++

What is the best way to declare an array size in C++?

Maybe something that grows dynamically?

```
string lineArr[];
```

I know without putting declaring an array size, the code above outputs an error, but is there a way to make it dynamic?

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](https://godbolt.org/g/mMuQhl)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah.  Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and never look back.

Answer (score 1):

A good method to declare an array size is to use a constant:

```
const unsigned int ARRAY_CAPACITY = 64U;
unsigned int my_array[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
```

For a dynamic array, use `std::vector`.

You could do all the memory management yourself instead:

```
unsigned int * p_array_start = new int[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an unspecified raw array use a `std::vector` like that:

```
 std::vector<string> lineArr;
```

The `std::vector` grows memory allocation as necessary, if you add to it using the `std::vector::push_back()` or `std::vector::insert()` functions.